# Regex for determining if any characters were input besides allowed input, and correcting the input accordingly

Tags: r, text, shiny

I have a small app with a numericInput that is meant to accept only 1-96. I want to make sure that if there is any input that is not 1-96, then it'll automatically correct it to 1. I have gotten this to work for specific inputs (eg input == 0, input == letters or symbols, input == empty space), but I would like to catch this using one expression if possible. My thought is to search the input and match any strings that contain anything that isn't exclusively 1-96. If it does contain something other than only 1-96, then it will reset the input to 1. I'm not great at regex yet, but this is my best attempt after a couple of days on the Googles.

I don't get any errors, but when I use this MRE, the app does not update `num_conds` when I input a letter. When I input a number above 96, it does update `num_conds`. When I plug this into my larger version and input the 'illegal' characters, the app crashes without a warning or error. I'm wondering if there is something wrong with my regex? Does anyone have any ideas?

**UPDATE**

I also just realized that the code will not allow a number with a 0, like 20, and will reset to 1. I'll continue to work on this, but please let me know if someone knows better. Thanks!

Here is my MRE:

```
#This is for ensuring only allowed characters are input

library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(htmlwidgets)

########## User interface ##########
ui = fluidPage(
  
  numericInput("num_conds", 
               label = "Conditions",
               min = 1,
               max = 96,
               value = 1),
  
)#close ui, fluidpage

########## Server logic #########

server = function(input, output, session) {
  
  observe({
    if (any(grepl('[^(?:(?!1-96).)*$]', input$num_conds)) == TRUE) {
      freezeReactiveValue(input, "num_conds")
      updateNumericInput(session, inputId = "num_conds", value = 1)
    }
  }) 
} # close server

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of regex, you could do a condition like `!input$num_conds %in% 1:96`.

Here is what that would look like in the context of your code:

```
#This is for ensuring only allowed characters are input

library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(htmlwidgets)

########## User interface ##########
ui = fluidPage(
  
  numericInput("num_conds", 
               label = "Conditions",
               min = 1,
               max = 96,
               value = 1),
  
)#close ui, fluidpage

########## Server logic #########

server = function(input, output, session) {
  
  observe({
    if (any(!input$num_conds %in% 1:96) == TRUE) {
      freezeReactiveValue(input, "num_conds")
      updateNumericInput(session, inputId = "num_conds", value = 1)
    }
  }) 
} # close server

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! This is about the 3rd time I've found that using %in% seems to just be a bit easier than regex. Thanks again!

Comment: regex is perfect when dealing with varied patterns in strings/characters. A numeric range does not require a tool of that complexity.